# In a research proposal for a computer science Ph.D. application, should I use the mathematical equations or just text to explain my ideas?

Tags: phd, application, research-proposal

I am writing a research proposal for Ph.D. admission. I am confused as to whether the research proposal for the Ph.D. application should be written like a formal paper. In a formal paper that I submit to a conference, I know that the paper will be reviewed by peers in our field, so I always try to write formal mathematical language when the plain text could not fully explain my ideas.

However, I am aware that some professors in the selection committee may not be in my field so they may not understand the equations in my field and I should therefore write down my ideas in a simpler way.

Am I overly concerned? Or I could just write the research proposal like it is a normal paper?

Comment: It depends on the field and the country. In a math department in the US, such a "proposal" is actually rather unusual in the first place, but if asked for one, both equations and text explaining the equations would be warranted.

Comment: On the one hand, for something like this, whatever is more comfortable for you is probably fine; in general, it's good to state the ideas in formal mathematical language as well as prose .